# Insert result from DOMXpath into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this DOMXpath query to retrieve some columns from another page.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8888/stockPrices.php");

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new \DOMDocument();

if($doc->loadHTML($html))
{
    $result = new \DOMDocument();
    $result->formatOutput = true;
    $table = $result->appendChild($result->createElement("table"));
    $thead = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("thead"));
    $tbody = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("tbody"));

    $table->setAttribute('class', 'table table-hover');

    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

    $newRow = $thead->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));

    foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id='kurstabell']/thead/tr/th[position()=2 or position()=3 or position()=8 or position()=9 or position()=10]") as $header)
    {
        $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("th", trim($header->nodeValue)));
    }

    foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id='kurstabell']/tbody/tr") as $row)
    {
        $newRow = $tbody->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));

        foreach($xpath->query("./td[position()=2 or position()=3 or position()=8 or position()=9 or position()=10]", $row) as $cell)
        {
            $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("td", trim(htmlentities($cell->nodeValue))));
        }
    }

    echo $result->saveXML($result->documentElement);
}
```

This generates four columns, `aktier`, `senaste`, `högst`, `lägst` and `omsatt`. But i dont know how to insert this to a MySQL table. Im thinking to first generate a array of the result, like:

```
                    Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aktie] => AAK AB
            [senaste] => 634,50
            [högst] => 638,50
            [lägst] => 622,50
            [omsatt] => 32 094 048
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aktie] => ABB Ltd
            [senaste] => 162,80
            [högst] => 163,30
            [lägst] => 161,90
            [omsatt] => 167 481 268
        )
(you get the hang of it..)
)
```

According to this image:
[image]

And then loop the array into the table. Something like this?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stock_list (`aktie`, `senaste`, `högst`, `lägst`, `omsatt`, `timestamp`) VALUES
        (:aktie, :senaste, :högst, :lägst, :omsatt)";
$query = $database->prepare($sql);

foreach($data as $stock){
$query->execute(array(':aktie' => $stock->stock,
                      ':senaste' => $stock->prevclose,
                      ':högst' => $stock->high,
                      ':lägst' => $stock->low,
                      ':omsatt' => $stock->volume
                      ));
}
```

**My question:**

- How do i populate the array with data?
- How do i loop the result in a mysql query?

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: `':timestamp' => NOW()` that's just all shades of wrong...as is `$query->database->prepare()` + `$query->execute`... what is `$query`, and what are you expecting it to be?

Comment: @AjeetKumar Im not using a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a work around. But it is currently doing what I'm asking for.

```
 // build query...
   $sql  = "INSERT INTO stocks";

    // columns to insert into...
    $sql .="(`name`, `closing`, `high`, `low`, `turn`, `timestamp`)";

    // implode values of $array...
    // notice array_chunk, this functions splits a big array into multi.
    $str = NULL;
    foreach (array_chunk($a, 5) as $row) {
        $str .= '("'. implode('","',$row).'",NOW()),';
    }

    // Remove last ',' (comma) from string
    // We added commas in the previous step
    $str = rtrim($str,',');
    $sql .= 'VALUES '. $str ;

   // execute query...
    $app = new Connection();

    $query = $app->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query->rowCount() <= 0) {
        echo "Something went wrong.";
        return false;
    }

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that what you really want is something along the lines of:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO stock_list
    (`aktie`, `senaste`, `högst`, `lägst`, `omsatt`, `timestamp`)
    VALUES
    (:aktie, :senaste, :högst, :lägst, :omsatt, NOW())';
$stmt = $app->getConnection()->prepare($query);
foreach ($data as $stock) {
    $stmt->execute(
        [
            ':aktie'   => $stock->aktie,
            ':senaste' => $stock->senaste,
            ':högst'   => $stock->{'högst'},
            ':lägst'   => $stock->{'lägst'},
            ':omsatt'  => $stock->omsatt,
        ]
    );
    $stmt->closeCursor();//might be required depending on DB driver, not for MySQL, though
}
```

Note that I call `NOW()` in the query string, and I don't bind that SQL function call to the parameters I execute the prepared statement with. All  in all though, a timestamp field is best set by the DB itself (with a `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the field definition). Then you can just leave the `timestamp` field out of your `INSERT` query, and it'll be set correctly for you.

I've also changed the way you're using the objects `stock`. From the var_dump I can see the properties aren't called `stock`, `high`, `low` and all that. The problem is, some of these property names (lägst for example) are a bit dodgy. You'll probably have to access those using a string, which can be done, like I did, by writing `$objVar->{'property name as string'}`.
If I were you, though, I'd look into ways of changing what `$data` actually looks like, and change the property names if at all possible.